# How to Load config from ~/.aws/config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

[change log](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2440) says
`Load config from ~/.aws/config if AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG is set.`
Couldn't find any examples or documentation regarding how to load the config. Any help!

Comment: If you set `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` to a truthy value, the SDK will automatically load the `~/.aws/config` file in the same way the AWS CLI would. What kind of example are you looking for?

Comment: In nodejs i can set the env variable to truthy value with           process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = true; How can I retrieve the region value in the config ? Mind sharing some code ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a little bit of magic in how aws-sdk loads the config

either set the env variable

```
export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG="true"
```

or before loading the aws-sdk set

```
process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = true;
```

Then load the aws module;

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

You can access the region directly by

```
AWS.config.region
```

Answer (score 2):

[The answer of sreenivas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699094/11311449) is correct. It also seems to be the only way to do this without writing a custom function.

I've traced it back in the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/d78f62f9d86066e67d3cb7302fe2656210732f07/lib/credentials/shared_ini_file_credentials.js#L98) and the the way it loads `~/.aws/config` is similar to this pseudocode:

```
if process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG:
  return load('~/.aws/credentials').overwrite('~/.aws/config')
else:
  return load('~/.aws/credentials')
```

This also means you can set the environment variable after `require('aws-sdk')`, as long as you do it before `new SharedIniFileCredentials({..})` or `credentials.refresh()`. Beware that `credentials.get()` will not work until the sessiontoken has expired.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for this:

- [HERE: Loading Node Credentials Shared](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)
- [HERE: Loading Node Credentials JSON File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html)
- [HERE: Getting Started NodeJS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html)

I would recommend installing the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) tool to set this up and then run `aws configure` in your terminal. By default, anything you're running on your local host will assume the credentials listed in your `config` file unless specified to assume a different profile.

Example from the first link:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials( { profile: 'work-account' } );
```

If you are using the CLI to run your script:

```
AWS_PROFILE=work-account node script.js
```

If you are using just the CLI tool and not JavaScript:

```
aws s3 ls --profile work-account
```

**Update:**

`config` and `credentials` are **made and referenced** at the **same time**. When you run `aws configure` it makes two files. The `credentials` file containing AccessKey and SecretKey - and the `config` file containing the response type and region. It is NOT necessary to explicitly define or reference the `config` file.

Comment: Am looking for 'config' not 'credentials'.

Comment: They are made at the same time. When you run `aws configure` it makes two files. The `credentials` file containing AccessKey and SecretKey - and the `config` file containing the response type and region. It is NOT necessary to explicitly define or reference the `config` file